# How do I replicate a score logic and a condition where object changes color when looked at for multiple objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

So I've been playing around with the cardboard demoscene that comes along with the cardboard SDK. The normal functionality is a floating red color cube that changes to green when looked at and respawns at a new location when the cardboard magnet is pressed. This script is attached to the collectable. I've changed the object and added a scoring logic. I've just included the bit for the cardboard for this question.

Now this works perfectly for a single object. But let's say I want multiple instances of the collectable on the terrain and I want the same color change logic to work for them apart from increasing score count when I collect them. How do I go about that?
I've tried naming all the collectables to the same name and explicitly finding gameobject with that name. But the logic doesnt seem to extend to the other collectables. Please help.

```
void start()
{
            head = Camera.main.GetComponent<StereoController> ().Head;
            startingPosition = transform.localPosition;
            CardboardGUI.IsGUIVisible = true;
            CardboardGUI.onGUICallback += this.OnGUI;
}
```

//This is the logic for changing the color of the object and I have added the score increment and timer decrement logic after this

```
void Update() {


RaycastHit hit;
        bool isLookedAt = GetComponent<Collider>().Raycast(head.Gaze, out hit, Mathf.Infinity);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = isLookedAt ? Color.green : Color.white;
        if (Cardboard.SDK.CardboardTriggered && isLookedAt) {
            // Teleport randomly.
            Vector3 direction = Random.onUnitSphere;
            direction.y = Mathf.Clamp(direction.y, 0.5f, 1f);
            float distance = 2 * Random.value + 1.5f;
            transform.localPosition = direction * distance;

//Score logic
}
//For placing the coconut back to original position on selecting reset.

void OnGUI() {
        if (!CardboardGUI.OKToDraw(this)) {
            return;
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50, 50, 200, 50), "Reset")) {
            transform.localPosition = startingPosition;
            //reset count and seconds
            count=0;
            Seconds=60;
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(50, 110, 200, 50), "Recenter")) {
            Cardboard.SDK.Recenter();
        }
}
```

Comment: Explain further what do you want. Do I understand correctly that you want X instances of a cube changing color on gaze (the one looked at changes color) but only one executing some score manipulating code in one? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Never mind, thanks. I got it to work. Yes I wanted multiple cubes but was finding a hard time replicating the score logic. Just separated the score display into another script and used the color change script for each instance of the cube to update the score of the other script.